# Parsing BLOB object present in iPhone SMS database

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, blob

I am developing an Android application to **update iOS SMS database**. I found that in iOS, MMS body (i.e. text of MMS and other information) is stored in **BLOB object**.

Sample BLOB object extracted from the database:

```
        streamtypedÅËÑ@ÑÑÑNSMutableAttributedStringÑÑNSAttributedStringÑÑNSObject
    ÖíÑÑÑNSMutableStringÑÑNSStringïÑ+ÔøºMerry 
    ChristmasÜÑiIíÑÑÑNSDictionaryïÑiíÑòò”__kIMFileTransferGUIDAttributeNameÜíÑòò$D060412D-D6A2-472D-9552-
0ACCDED7E9B5ÜíÑòò__kIMMessagePartAttributeNameÜíÑÑÑNSNumberÑÑNSValueïÑ*Ñõ
õÜÜôíÑöõíÑòò__kIMMessagePartAttributeNameÜíÑüû°õÜÜÜI have the following questions.
```

My aim is to update the text of the above BLOB object from **“Merry Christmas” to “Happy new year”**. I found that when I simply replace the text, the MMS body is not visible on the target iOS device (after inserting database to the iOS device). But I found that if I replace the string “Merry Christmas” with other string having the **same length**, it works properly and MMS body is visible with the updated text on the iOS device.

1. How to **parse** such type of BLOB objects to understand its details?
2. I think the BLOB objects contain information about the length of the text present in MMS. Which **fields** in the above BLOB object can possibly **store information about the length**?
3. Is “**streamtype**” a file type? (As the BLOB object starts with that string) If yes, how to parse such type of files?

I'd appreciate any suggestions on this issue.